# How to Change the Default Home Page for the WordPress Dashboard?

Tags: admin, wp-admin, login, dashboard, authentication

Is it possible to change the Default "Home" admin page when logging into the WordPress Dashboard?

I thought about a couple of possibilities...

1. Substitute the content on the Dashboard home page with custom
   content.
2. Redirect to a different admin page within the WordPress Dashboard
   upon successful login.

If it is possible to do either of the two options, what hooks would you recommend utilizing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Easy enough, decided to just do the redirect option. I used the [`wp_login`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login) action hook. You could also probably use this for redirecting your users to ANY page on your website. You can also check user capabilities from the `$user` Object passed in as a function parameter if you want to send different user levels to different pages.

```
/* Redirect the user logging in to a custom admin page. */
function new_dashboard_home($username, $user){
    if(array_key_exists('administrator', $user->caps)){
        wp_redirect(admin_url('admin.php?page=c2c-overview', 'http'), 301);
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'new_dashboard_home', 10, 2);
```