# admin menu: use default "general" page for theme settings using add_menu_page and add_submenu_page

Tags: admin-menu, theme-options

How can I make my theme settings admin menu showing "general" as default page while keeping its menu title as "theme settings"?

I mean at the moment I got this using `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page`:

[image]

But I want to have "general"... I am struggling to figure this out... Is it not possible?

Comment: Have a look at [this] (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/65822/134934) ,
Some guy used hooks on wp-admin.php to redirect to desired page

Comment: I am not sure how doing this I would be able to change the title to "general", and without get duplicated pages...

Comment: So when someone clicks on the "Theme settings" (with the cog icon) you want them to be on "General" page - where the red arrow points on your image?

Comment: @Greg36 yes. This is what I am trying to have.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a submenu page with the same slug as the menu page. E.g.

```
$menu_slug = "my_menu_slug";
$desired_capability = "manage_options"; //Or whatever you need
$menu_page_callback = "menu_page_callback_function";

add_menu_page(
    "Page Title", 
    "Menu Title", 
    $desired_capability, 
    $menu_slug, 
    $menu_page_callback
);

add_submenu_page(
    $menu_slug, 
    "Submenu Page Title", 
    "Submenu Menu Title",
    $desired_capability, 
    $menu_slug, 
    $menu_page_callback
);
//Note, the 5th and 6th parameters here are the same as above. This 
//overrides the first submenu title. Now clicking the 
//menu title and the first submenu item will navigate to the same page, 
//generated by the menu_page_callback function.
```